# Asp.net controller Passing multiple parameters from Query String

Tags: asp.net, controller, query-string

I have a controller action and I want to pass several parameters by query string.I know how to do with one parameter:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> PortfolioCat([FromQuery]int curpage = 1)
```

How to extend that? Should I just write something like:

public async Task PortfolioCat([FromQuery]int curpage = 1, param2, param3) etc..

Comment: `PortfolioCat([FromQuery]int curpage = 1, [FromQuery]int param2, [FromQuery] int param3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from Query String by using below code. If you use URL like this https://localhost:44335/Home/PortfolioCat/10?param2=10 then id will receive 10 value. If you use int curpage then you will not receive value.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PortfolioCat(int id, string param2)
{
  return View();
}
```

if you use like this Url 
https://localhost:44335/Home/PortfolioCat?curpage=10&param2=10 then you can use below structure.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PortfolioCat(int curpage, string param2)
{
   return View();
}
```

and This is Controller Action of ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Controller and ASP.NET Core Controller are different. Because many things don't support in .NET Core of .NET Framework.